# daimajia AndroidSwipeLayout Button click issue in Activity

Tags: android, swipe, buttonclick

I am using `SwipeLayout` in my activity.

Activity is having 2 buttons. On button click, I want to set respective fragment on bottom layout and swipe view programmatically. And on close, it should set replace bottom layout with default fragment so that on swipe it displays default fragment.

When I set default fragment in onClose method of swipeLayout's addSwipeListener, it does not listen to button click.

This works fine with RecyclerView but now I want same in activity

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="6dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="6dp"

    xmlns:swipe="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <com.daimajia.swipe.SwipeLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipe_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <!-- Bottom View Start-->
        <!--What you want to show-->

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/sub_item_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light">              
        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- Bottom View End-->

        <!-- Surface View Start -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/frame_list_card_item"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="9"
                android:background="#eefeef"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="10dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/title_text"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="this is the Title this is the Title this is the Title this is the Title this is the Title "
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textSize="15sp"/>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/container_list_content"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="this is description text this is description text this is description text this is description text this is description text this is description text this is description text this is description text this is description text this is description text this is description text "
                        android:textSize="13sp"/>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                         <Button
                            android:id="@+id/btn_one"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:minHeight="0dp"
                            android:text="4"/>

                         <Button
                            android:id="@+id/btn_two"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:minHeight="0dp"
                            android:text="5"/>
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <!--What you want to show in SurfaceView-->
                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <!-- Surface View End -->
       </com.daimajia.swipe.SwipeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**JAVA**

```
package com.sp.spsamples3.activities;

public class SwipeLayoutActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    SwipeLayout mSwipeLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_swipe_layout);

        mSwipeLayout = (SwipeLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe_layout);

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.sub_item_container, new DefaultFragment()).commit();
        mSwipeLayout.setShowMode(SwipeLayout.ShowMode.LayDown);

        mSwipeLayout.addSwipeListener(new SwipeLayout.SwipeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onStartOpen(SwipeLayout layout) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onOpen(SwipeLayout layout) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStartClose(SwipeLayout layout) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onClose(SwipeLayout layout) {
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.sub_item_container, new DefaultFragment()).commit();
            }

            @Override
            public void onUpdate(SwipeLayout layout, int leftOffset, int topOffset) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onHandRelease(SwipeLayout layout, float xvel, float yvel) {

            }
        });
        initClicks();

    }

    private void initClicks() {

        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_one)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.i("sp testing", "1 clicked");
                setFragment(new ScreenOneFragment());
                mSwipeLayout.open(true);
            }
        });

        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_two)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.i("sp testing", "2 clicked");
                setFragment(new ScreenTwoFragment());
                mSwipeLayout.open(true);
            }
        });
    }

    private void setFragment(Fragment fragment) {
             getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.sub_item_container, fragment).commit();
    }

}
```